# Wso2-devstudio export car file error with UTF8 encoding

Tags: windows, utf-8, wso2, wso2-esb

I face the following problem till trying to make export of .car file via wso2-devstudion from composite application project. The this is the error from the error log:

```
"!MESSAGE An error occured while creating the carbon archive file
!STACK 0
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0xce (at char #822, byte #37)"
```

So the problem was with using of not Latin characters in one of the proxy services "envelope requests". Under Windows 7 (x64).

Answer (score 3):

Solution of this problem is to add the following line in the Eclipse.ini file of your wso2-devstudio IDE:

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

After that you should restart the IDE and problem is gone.

Comment: This answer was useful for me. I've imported a project from Linux to my Windows 7 x64. If I'd opened any xml file with ESB Editor, the accents turned into unreachable signs. In XML Editor they opened well. I changed encoding in all Preferences with no success. This was the only way that works for me. Thanks!